# libreadline: When is the function "_rl_parse_colors()" called?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, colors, readline

I am working on Bash 5.0 from [GNU repository](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tag/?h=bash-5.0). I wanted to debug the functions that parse the colors so I went to the colors files:

1. `bash-5.0/lib/readline/colors.c` - [link](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/colors.c?h=bash-5.0)
2. `bash-5.0/lib/readline/parse-colors.c` - [link](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/parse-colors.c?h=bash-5.0)

I added prints like that in the function `_rl_parse_colors`:

```
printf ("[*] INSIDE _rl_parse_colors");
```

I did it almost in any function but after I compiled it, I ran it but it didn't print my debug prints:

```
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bash-5.0# ./bash -c 'echo -e "\033[31mHello\e[0m World"'
Hello World
```

I also tried to access the bash and then run it:

```
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bash-5.0# ./bash
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bash-5.0# echo $BASH_VERSION                                                         
5.0.0(8)-release
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bash-5.0# ./bash -c 'echo -e "\033[31mHello\e[0m World"'
Hello World
```

It print the "Hello" with red but not my prints.
Is it related to the fact that I am using `echo`? I don't see how it could affect because eventfully, the bash wraps the STDOUT of the command so it should draw the string with red.

Comment: Does your `./bash` link with the readline library from the sources you compiled? I think readline is separate `.so` file. Try something along `LD_PRELOAD=the_path_to_compiled_libreadline.so ./bash`

Comment: inside the readline library I only have `.c`, `.o` and `.a` file extensions

Comment: @E235: Does your terminal have colour capabilities? What does `tput colors` say?

Comment: @user1934428 yes it has, if I run `./bash -c 'echo -e "\033[31mHello\e[0m World"'` it prints the "Hello" with red

Comment: i did not read the code but i dont think readline would care about colors in the output.

Comment: @pynexj You can find some of the code here:
https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/parse-colors.c?h=bash-5.0

You might right but the functions looks like this is what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the code (I'm on the `bash-5.1-testing` branch) --

In file `lib/readline/parse-colors.c`:

```
300 void _rl_parse_colors(void)
301 {
302 #if defined (COLOR_SUPPORT)
303   const char *p;                /* Pointer to character being parsed */
304   char *buf;                    /* color_buf buffer pointer */
305   int state;                    /* State of parser */
306   int ind_no;                   /* Indicator number */
307   char label[3];                /* Indicator label */
308   COLOR_EXT_TYPE *ext;          /* Extension we are working on */
309
310   p = sh_get_env_value ("LS_COLORS");
311   if (p == 0 || *p == '\0')
312     {
313       _rl_color_ext_list = NULL;
314       return;
315     }
...
```

There's only one call of `_rl_parse_colors()` in file `lib/readline/readline.c`:

```
1215 /* Initialize the entire state of the world. */
1216 static void
1217 readline_initialize_everything (void)
1218 {
....
1287
1288 #if defined (COLOR_SUPPORT)
1289   if (_rl_colored_stats || _rl_colored_completion_prefix)
1290     _rl_parse_colors ();
1291 #endif
1292
```

The vars names `_rl_colored_stats` and `_rl_colored_completion_prefix` sound to be for these readline settings:

```
[STEP 101] $ bind -v | grep color
set colored-completion-prefix off
set colored-stats off
[STEP 102] $
```

I just verified that these steps would enter `_rl_parse_colors()`:

1. Turn on `colored-completion-prefix` or `colored-stats` in `~/.inputrc`.
2. [optional] Set (and export) `LS_COLORS`
3. Start an **interactive** shell with your compiled bash (`./bash`)

---

According to bash manual (`man bash`):

> `colored-completion-prefix (Off)`
>
> > If set to On, when listing completions, readline displays the common prefix of the set of possible  completions using a different color.  The color definitions are taken from the value of
> > the **LS_COLORS** environment variable.
>
> `colored-stats (Off)`
>
> > If set to On, readline displays possible completions using different colors to indicate  their
> > file  type.  The color definitions are taken from the value of the **LS_COLORS** environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, after I created the file `~/.inputrc` and added the lines `set colored-completion-prefix on` and `set colored-stats on`, I loaded the compiled bash and saw my prints. But it runs only one time after I start Bash. I want to know where is the place Bash convert the string to colors each time your run `echo -e ...` but it should be for a different question.

Comment: as the func name `readline_initialize_everything` indicates its an init func.